# Linux DMZ in a Windows Network

Tags: windows, security, linux-networking

I'm a wet-behind-the-ears reluctant sysadmin, so I'm playing catch-up here. I've come across the term DMZ before, but I never looked into it until just recently. In fact I'm still not sure exactly what's involved in the setup; I'll be continuing my studies and test projects.

But suffice it to say I like the idea.

I have a small-business customer for whom I'd like to implement the concept. He's running WSE 2012 R2 with a handful of client machines/VMs.

The trouble is that he won't want to justify the cost of a Server 2012 R2 license, especially for this sole purpose in his small domain.

So my question is this: will I be able to use a non-domain-joined instance of CentOS (for example) running in a VM for his DMZ?

**EDIT:**

With the help of commenters I'm able to better phrase my question:

Will I be able to insert a non-domain-joined instance of CentOS (for example) running in a VM into his DMZ without disrupting the internal Windows network?

Comment: Usually speaking: You never join a server in the domain when it's in the DMZ !! So, if it can help to answer your question, it's correct as it's already a bestpractice to not let a domain-joined computer enter the DMZ. That imply too much port to be open between the LAN<->DMZ too. What is the role the server will have ? you forget to tell that

Comment: A DMZ is a network segment more than it is a specific server.

Comment: @yagmoth555: Yes, I'd already discovered that in my research, thanks—no DCs or domain-joined machines in the DMZ. Are you asking about the Linux DMZ server I'm proposing? It wouldn't have _any_ roles, I suppose... the OS would exist solely as a security device. Am I understanding things correctly here?

Comment: @JoelCoel: Mush... I was hoping to gain clarity here, not confusion  ;-) I'm at a loss how to configure it then, if not with a separate OS in a VM. Maybe you know of some config references you could point me to?

Comment: @JoelCoel: Never mind, I just found about three hundred of them  :-)

Comment: @JoelCoel: But more to my question—will the CentOS idea work?

Comment: You set up a dmz as a dedicated network port or address range/routes in your router or gateway firewall. If you're looking for an OS to act as a security device, that's more in the firewall or UTM space than DMZ space. Think SonicWall, Untangle, Watchguard, Fortinet, Cisco ASA.

Comment: @JoelCoel: OK, got it—I think. It's just that most everything I'm finding talks about putting your forward-facing services on a "server in the DMZ."

Comment: @InteXX A DMZ is just a separate area on the network that is locked down and secured from the rest of the network with some form of firewall between it and the rest of the network. You can place any number of servers within the DMZ. The server itself is not the DMZ, you are just placing it there to better secure it from other things on the network and the internet. Think of a deposit box inside of a bank vault. The bank vault is the DMZ, the deposit box is the server. Nothing special about the deposit box, apart from it's location within the secure area.

Comment: @Steve365: Hey Steve, that helps! Thanks :-) So I guess the answer to the CentOS/Windows question is yes.

Comment: @InteXX Have a read of this, it might help - http://www.aidanfinn.com/2011/10/can-i-mix-lan-and-dmzinternet-vms-on-a-hyper-v-hostcluster/. The answer to your question is NO. The CentOS VM is NOT the DMZ. You can certainly have a CentOS VM connected to the portion of your network that is treated as your DMZ, but the server itself is not a DMZ. If you want a more specific answer then update your question with details on exactly what you're looking to achieve (not, "I want a DMZ", but "I want to deploy application X in a secure way on this network for Y clients with this network topology - how?")

Comment: @Steve365: "You can certainly have a CentOS VM connected to the portion of your network that is treated as your DMZ, but the server itself is not a DMZ." That pretty well clears it up for me, thanks. Would you care to enter it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @InteXX Done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**To answer your first question:** You can certainly have a CentOS VM connected to the portion of your network that is treated as your DMZ, but the server itself is not a DMZ

**To answer your second question:** Yes, placing a non-domain joined CentOS VM into a DMZ without disrupting the internal network is certainly possible if done correctly.

---

**A bit more detail**

A DMZ is a separate area of your network that is secured from unwanted traffic from both the rest of your internal LAN and the outside world (the internet). Often this takes the form of a perimeter network, i.e. your network looks something like this

```
Internet <-> DMZ <-> Internal LAN
```

Your internal LAN will have your usual clients, servers, etc. on it and will be locked down so the outside world cannot access the network devices on this portion of the network, although depending on your policies these devices quite possibly can access the internet (outbound traffic permitted by default, inbound blocked).

The DMZ will contain servers that need to be accessed from the internet. You lock down the DMZ completely, then only open the specific ports that you need to in order to enable the services you are exposing to the outside world to function (e.g. port 80 and 443 TCP for a standard web server).

In a traditional physical DMZ setup you would use your router to setup VLANs and put the DMZ on a separate VLAN to the internal network. You would then setup firewall rules to only allow the servers on the DMZ VLAN to be accessible on specific ports. Taking the web server example again you could open ports 80 and 443 to the outside world for inbound connections, and also open port 22 (ssh) inbound to the internal LAN only for management purposes. Often you would also setup outbound rules to prohibit outbound network access except on the specific ports that you need, or in response to permitted inbound network traffic.

You are referring to a virtualised environment (presumably in Hyper-V). It is certainly possible to setup multiple VLANs and route these to a single Hyper-V host (possibly using multiple physical network cards on the host). You can then use the virtualised switches in Hyper-V to segregate internal VMs (on the internal VLAN) from the servers in the DMZ (on the DMZ VLAN).

If you have come across the term DMZ previously in the context of ISP supplied home broadband routers then be aware that this is not really the same thing. All these routers tend to do is open up every port from the outside world to a specific interface on the switch. No VLANs are involved, it's all on the same physical switch. Unless you are very careful to add additional security this is generally a massive security hole. Enterprise level DMZs described in brief above are a far more secure affair when configured properly.

*Side note. I'm not a networking expert. If anyone who actually understands what they're talking about reads this and wants to chip in with corrections, please feel free... :)*

Comment: Bingo. Couldn't have said it better myself ;-) Yes, it's Hyper-V. Thanks for the extra tips on VLAN—I'll look into that. I especially appreciate the clarification on Ent.DMZ vs Isp.DMZ—I was wondering about that exact thing. Thank you.